# Nuxt SPA Firebase Hosting: Read Configuration from the __/firebase/init.js file

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting

As you know, all firebase hosting is provided with a `__/firebase/init.js` which contains the apiKey, project ID etc.

I am trying to host my SPA in a manner that it reads the configuration form that file instead of it being hard coded during build.

Here is my nuxt.config.js:

```
[
      '@nuxtjs/firebase',
      {
        config: {
          production: {
            apiKey: '',
            appId: '',
            authDomain: '',
            messagingSenderId: '',
            projectId: '',
            storageBucket: '',
          },
        },

        onFirebaseHosting: true,

        // customEnv: true,
        services: {
          auth: {
            persistent: 'local',
            initialize: {
              onAuthStateChangedAction: 'onAuthStateChanged',
            },
            ssr: false, // default
          },
        },
      },
```

When I deploy the application in Firebase Hosting, I get this error:
[image: Firebase SPA Config error]

As you can see, the configuration did not get fetched.

The source code has these hints:

https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/blob/217ac819e36a8a74159eb3c2625a98f14ed5cfd0/lib/module.js#L106

https://github.com/nuxt-community/firebase-module/blob/217ac819e36a8a74159eb3c2625a98f14ed5cfd0/lib/sw-templates/firebase-auth-sw.js#L7

```
const ignorePaths = <%= serialize(options.ignorePaths) %>

<% if (options.loadFromFirebaseHosting) { %>
// Only works on Firebase hosting!
importScripts('/__/firebase/<%= options.firebaseVersion %>/firebase-app.js')
importScripts('/__/firebase/<%= options.firebaseVersion %>/firebase-auth.js')
importScripts('/__/firebase/init.js')
```

I am wondering if this is possible with an SPA since it's all pre-built. And can I somehow dynamically generate the config from this file?

Answer (score 0):

The `/__/firebase/init.js` script is special, as Firebase Hosting automatically determines for which project you are calling it and returns the configuration settings for that project. In order to be able to do that, it needs to execute in an environment that knows of Firebase, such as Firebase Hosting itself or the Hosting emulator.

What you **can** do is inject the necessary configuration into your app, instead of pulling it from `/__/firebase/init.js`. The configuration block in both cases looks like this:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  //...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Also see the Firebase documentation for [setting up in Node.js apps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup#node.js-apps), which is closest to what you're doing in that case.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean set the configuration keys like apiKey, appId in the app itself? That's what I am trying to avoid so that my app will work in any firebase hosting environment with that environment's configurations without me hard coding it in the SPA. The current hosting environment that I am testing it in is also a Firebase Hosting environment. And I am using the `nuxt-firebase` module.

Comment: Hmm... in that case you might want to check what `init.js` actually contains, and whether those are the API keys for the project you are trying to use.

Comment: Yes, whatever I was supposed to have in the nuxt.config.js file is in there and it's dynamically generated for every firebase hosting project.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure where the error is coming from in that case. I hope somebody else spots it.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the help.